# How to replace user control in cell into the Grid. WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

I have a `Grid` with 5 rows and 5 columns. I creating this `Grid` dynamically. Every cell contains custom user control. I would like to replace the user control dynamically with other user control at given row and column. You can see the method implementation which creates the `Grid` [here](http://pastebin.com/DLYGrzG2).

My question is how to replace the user control at given row and column after the `Grid` is already created? Sorry if my English is bad!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will probably fit your needs

```
public void ReplaceItemAt(Grid grid, FrameworkElement fe, int row, int col)
{
    // clear desired cell
    var items = grid.Children
        .Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == col)
        .ToArray();
    foreach(var item in items) grid.Children.Remove(item);

    // make sure the new item is positioned correctly
    Grid.SetRow(fe, row);
    Grid.SetColumn(fe, col);

    // insert the new item into the grid
    grid.Children.Add(fe);
}
```

Comment: Very good Implementation and thanks for you help. You solved my problem.